# multiple submit button values with multipart/form-data

Tags: html, servlets, multipartform-data

Working on a Multipart File Upload form. Using Java with Servlet 3.0. It seems with multipart, the value of the submit button is not passed to the server?

e.g.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/servlet">
    <input type="hidden" name="mode"   value="image">
    <input type="hidden" name="id"     value="123"> 
    <input type="file"   name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
</form>
```

In a regular post, you would just check the value of the "action" parameter. How do you access this in a multipart form? I tried examining the Parts in the request, and it's just not there.

e.g.

```
Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
System.out.println("parts: "+parts.size());
for(Part part : parts){
    System.out.println(part.getName());
}
```

Outputs:

```
parts: 3
mode
id
file
```

As in...

```
    String mode = request.getParameter("mode"); //reads "image"
    String id   = request.getParameter("id");   //read "123"
    String action = request.getParameter("action"); //reads null
```

How do you solve this one?

Answer (score 2):

Have a hidden field declared and set its value based on the Submit button clicked , before you submit , using Javascript

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitType" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

first import multipart jar file in your program then 
try to use multipartrequest class for accessing multipart data from your form -

```
MultipartRequest mpr=new MultipartRequest(request,"C:");
String ad=mpr.getParameter("made");                    // read "image"
String ad=mpr.getParameter("id");                    // read "123"
String ad=mpr.getParameter("action");    // if u submit from from upload then it read "upload" or submit from delete then it read "delete" String .
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: worked for me! As a hint for everyone else: You can download the multipart stuff from this site: http://www.servlets.com/cos/